# Inapp browser cordova not opening

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Here is my code it's not complicated and it was working before, but now the app isn't loading the in app browser unless i tap on the button (it's in a ontouchstart) and then  exit the app (run in background) then open the app.

```
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "location=yes");
```

What could cause this to happen? it only happens on ios
Cheers

Comment: Try to run your code after a period of time using JavaScript setTimeout , and make sure the code is after you reference of cordova.js file.

Comment: its well after all that i mean im in the middle of the app everything has loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

InAppBrowser is currently having problems with IOSX as they have changed the CSP.

Solution is to add "content="default-src 'self' gap://ready" under your meta tag meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" in index.html

More info:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6928